# Logger save log to file

Tags: java, logging, glassfish

I'm building a Web Application only for WebServices in Java and using Glassfish server to deploy it on Mac OS X.

I wanted to save all the logs to file using Logger. I have coded this method and called it on the contextInitialized listener method.

```
private void ConfigLogger() {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/log.properties");
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if(inputStream != null){
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my configuration file

```
.level = WARNING
pkg.subpkg.JobClass.level = INFO


handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler


java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = LogBluetoothWebService_%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 10485760
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 20
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

The application is generating too much files only when deploying the application all with this message

```
SEVERE: feb 21, 2016 10:46:15 PM com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream log
```

And the files are in

```
/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config
```

How can I solve this problem with this too much logs?
How can I set the path in the configuration file to set a relative path to the web application to save the logs file.